# Return a String in Redux Thunk Function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

Is it possible to return a string from a Redux Thunk function. Scenario is I want to get a 'success' or 'fail' string based on the API that is called in the Redux thunk function.

Dispatch Called:

```
  const value =  dispatch(postData(data));
  console.log(value)
```

Thunk Function:

```
export const postData = (data) => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    jwtAxios
      .post(`/setdata`, data)
      .then((data) => {
        if (data.status === 200) {
          dispatch({type: FETCH_SUCCESS});
            **Return a String here**
              return 'success'

        } else {
          dispatch({
            type: FETCH_ERROR,
            payload: <IntlMessages id='message.somethingWentWrong' />,
          });
        }
      })
      .catch((error) => {
      });
  };
};
```

Comment: Sure. How are you accessing the returned value? What is the issue, if there is one? Can you update your post to include a [minimal, complete, and reproducible code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that includes all the relevant code you are working with?

Comment: I want to access like this  const value =  dispatch(function(data)); but I am getting undefined as a result. Can you please redirect me to any example which do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code isn't returning anything from the thunk function. It should return the Promise chain created by `jwtAxios` and the calling code should wait for the Promise to resolve before accessing any returned resolved values. Arrow functions with a body ***don't*** implicitly return any values.

Example:

```
export const postData = (data) => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    return jwtAxios // <-- return Promise chain
      .post(`/setdata`, data)
      .then((data) => {
        if (data.status === 200) {
          dispatch({ type: FETCH_SUCCESS });
          return 'success';
        } else {
          dispatch({
            type: FETCH_ERROR,
            payload: <IntlMessages id='message.somethingWentWrong' />,
          });
        }
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        dispatch({ type: FETCH_ERROR, payload: error.message });
      });
  };
};
```

Caller should wait for Promise to resolve:

```
const result = await dispatch(postData(data));
```

or

```
dispatch(postData(data))
  .then(result => {
    ...
  });
```

Comment: Thank you for very helpful answer. So a Promise chain is returned from the Thunk Function, Got it. Scenario is, I don't want to create a redux state for a 'success' or 'fail' message. Is there any other possible scenario where I can know my Axios call failed or successful without any state. 
If there is no possible way of doing that, should I create a global redux state for success/fail messages or a multiple states for different APIs.  Thanks again!

Comment: @shehwar You could return a failure value from the other logic branches and check this in the UI, or if you don't need to dispatch the `FETCH_SUCCESS` or `FETCH_ERROR` actions you can simply just return `jwtAxios.post(`/setdata`, data)` without chaining from it, and chain the `.then` and `.catch` in the UI from the dispatched action for the success/fail (*resolved/rejected*). You'd need to throw an error for any non-200 response status. FYI you can specify a `validateStatus` function to throw/reject any non-200 response status. (https://github.com/axios/axios#request-config)